# How do I run the same piece of code for multiple text inputs without using select case?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have eight aspx text inputs labelled txtBoookingId1, txtBookingId2 etc etc. I have a sub which handles eight buttons clicks as the code is more or less the same for each. I have it so it knows which one is pressed. I want to run "booking = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(**txtBookingId2**.Text.Trim, "[^0-9.]", "")" to trim off any letters but I want the txtBokingId2 part to be the correct one based on which button was clicked.

**Is there an easier way of doing this than using a Select with eight cases and the same line of code in each with only the bolded above changed slightly?** I tried having a string "Dim txt As String = "txtBookingId" & btnPressed.ToString" (which would give txtBookingId1, txtBookingId2 etc based on button then using that in place of txtBookingId2 but it's not valid code as there isn't an text input named "txt".

Code decides which button is clicked based on where CommandArgument=1,2,3 in the text input etc

Comment: Can you add a piece of code please? for better understanding.

Comment: You can cast the sender back to a Button and get it's ID.